# Can we download Azure deployment files with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is it possible to download the deployment JSON file (the template) for an Azure resource using Azure CLI?
The equivalent in PowerShell seems to be this command.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/save-azdeploymenttemplate?view=azps-2.0.0

In this case, the resource is a Cloud Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `az group deployment export` is the command to do this.

```
az group deployment export --name
                           --resource-group
                           [--subscription]
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-export

I'm not sure what the best way to save that output to a file is, but it looks like you can redirect to files using > on Bash command lines.